# MongoDB query returning wrong results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I have two computers that communicate to the same MongoDB collection. I will give a simple example on what they do, I use PyMongo as the CLI interface

Computer A:
Every 1s:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient
# Create payload
client = MongoClient(mongo_html)
collection_post = client["MyCollection"].posts
pay_load = {
    "number": 10,
    "is_processed": False
}
collection_post.insert_one(pay_load)
```

Computer B:
Every 10s:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient
# Create payload
client = MongoClient(mongo_html)
collection_post = client["MyCollection"].posts

all_docs = collection_post.find({"is_processed": False})
for doc in all_docs:
    do_work(doc)
    collection_post.update({"_id": ObjectID(doc["_id"])}, {"is_processed", True})
```

But the problem I face is that in computer B, I sometimes get documents that have "is_processed" True into the "all_docs" cursor. I assume this is related to MongoDB replication procedure?

Is there a better way to handle this? Can I somehow "force" Computer B to get a "updated" version of the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know the fact in MongoDB that:

> Reads may miss matching documents that are updated during the course of the read operation.

You can read [David Glasser's post](https://blog.meteor.com/mongodb-queries-dont-always-return-all-matching-documents-654b6594a827) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I am facing! However, his fix is not applicable to my issue, is there a way around this in some other way? Should I add a delay after updating? If yes, then how much delay do you think I need?

Comment: @Dammi: In my business case, instead of `insert` and `read` with MongoDB, I use Redis for caching. Then every 5 minutes, I write them to db.